# HTML/JavaScript - Replace onClick() (in HTML) with JavaScript (addEventListener not working)

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

I've tried a few solutions on here already, but I just can't seem to make them work.

I have a Flask app that uses HTML combined with JavaScript to display a handful of web pages.

Right now, I still have some inline code (which also prevents me from setting a proper CSP-Header), namely <... onClick="function()">.

Right now my HTML looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <...other stuff...>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'admin.js') }}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="topnav">
            <a href="#" id="logout"> <b>Logout</b></a>
            <a href="#" id="adminView"> AdminView</a>
            <a href="#" id="tanView">Show TAN</a>

        </div>
        <...other stuff...>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript like this:

```
bunchOfFunctions


function logout() {
    window.location.replace(URL_SLO)
}

function adminView() {
    window.location.replace(URL_ADMIN_BASE)
}

function tanView() {
    window.location.replace(URL_TAN)
}
```

I have attempted to import the Script at the bottom of the HTML file and then add Eventlisteners like so:

```
document.getElementById("logout").addEventListener("click", logout)
```

But all that does is do nothing when I click on the buttons again, not even an error.

---

On a related note, it'd be cool if I could download the Axios script and use it locally, since, y'know, security. But when I merely copy the content of the link and try to integrate it that way, the imports don't work.

Edit: Copied the working version of the snippet, not the broken one.

It now only works in one script, the other one doesn't.

tan.html:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
        <... other stuff ...>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="topnav">
        <a href="#" id="logoutButtonTAN"> <b>Logout</b></a>
        {% if isAdmin %}
        <a href="#" id="adminViewButtonTAN"> <b>AdminView</b></a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <... other stuff ...>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'tan.js') }}"></script>

</html>
```

and the corresponding JS file:

```
 function logout() {
  window.location.replace(URL_SLO)
}

function adminView() {
  const URL_ADMIN_BASE = URL_BASE + "api/adminsans/";
  window.location.replace(URL_ADMIN_BASE)
}


function mount() {
  ...other stuff
  
  document.getElementById('logoutButtonTAN').addEventListener('click', logout);

  document.getElementById('adminViewButtonTAN').addEventListener('click', adminView);
}


window.onload = mount

other stuff...
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("logout")` — by ID means "by ID', not "by lower-cased text content"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[onclick](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp)
The onclick attribute fires on a mouse click on the element.

[getElementById](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)
Get the element with the specified ID

You must use ID

```js
document.getElementById('logout').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('logout');
});
```

```html
 <div class="topnav">
  <a href="#" id="logout"> <b>Logout</b></a>
  <a href="#" id="adminView"> AdminView</a>
  <a href="#" id="tanView">Show TAN</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That one was on me, I copied the working script and forgot to adjust that part. However, that only works on one of my pages, the second one is mostly the same (imports the proper JS file at the end, and the code snippets are:         <a href="#" id="logoutButtonTAN"> <b>Logout</b></a> and    document.getElementById('logoutButtonTAN').addEventListener('click', logout);
- but the logout function only works in the first file, despite it being in both and having (technically the same code). Only difference is an onload function in the second file.

Comment: You need to debug your code, no one will help you with this. try use console.log(document.getElementById('#yourelement')) and check if your script can access the element, maybe your script works before element loaded, then use DOMContentLoaded event to wait load your page